# Implementing Sliding Navigation Drawer with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am working on android project and I am trying to implement ActionBarSherlock with the Sliding Navigation Drawer.

The actual menu is working fine however, the 3 line icon (I think if I remember correctly its called the burger icon) doesn't appear, instead the less than icon for going back to the parent, however clicking it does show/hide the menu.

Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment frag = new MainFragment();
        t.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag);
        t.commit();

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_drawer);

        NavigationManagerAdapter menuAdapter = new NavigationManagerAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        menuAdapter.add(new NavigationMenuItem("MenuItem", "MENU_PRODUCTS", GuiType.TEXTVIEW, null));
        menuAdapter.add(new NavigationMenuItem("MenuItem2", "MENU_TEST", GuiType.TEXTVIEW_SUMMARY, "This is a summary", mSpecificClickListener));

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(menuAdapter);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Set the title on the action when drawer open
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("hello");
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerClickListener());
    }

    public OnClickListener mSpecificClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Specific click listener used", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Even if I think this doesn't seem to change anything, try `return true` in onOptionsItemSelected. Also, you can use this library which allows you to display an icon at the top left with ABS: https://github.com/sockeqwe/SlidingMenu - HTH

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

**Note: ActionBarDrawerToggle which changes indicator to three-line-icon is just works for AppCompat follow one of these ways! (2nd is Strongly recommended and easier)**

it's NOT as simple as you thing...

to set ActionBar(Sherlock) UpIndicator as NavigationDrawerToggle, you should use one of these:

1. SlidingMenu : https://github.com/sockeqwe/SlidingMenu

this is a library which includes a navigationdrawer himself which have differents from NavigationDrawer

**Differents :**

- **moves content instead of drawing menu on the content!**
- **fades menu on openning/closing instead of fading content**

also

- it have some bugs in gestures
- source is completely editable

[image: slidingmenu]
<sub>(source: [alexanderblom.se](http://alexanderblom.se/images/spotify-menu.png))</sub>

2. SherlockNavigationDrawer : https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/SherlockNavigationDrawer

this library just bring you UpIndicator as NavigationDrawerToggle feature!
it should be used blong Android Support Library!

[image: navdrawer]

Comment: second one is strongly recommended!

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines

```
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); 
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would have worked perfectly if you were using **ActionBarCompat** instead of **ActionBarSherlock** because ABS does not have support for this. For ABS remove `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` and add this line :

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
```